# Create constants for offsets into a list

Tags: python

I have a list similar to this:

```
host_info = ['stackoverflow.com', '213.213.214.213', 'comments', 'desriprion', 'age']
```

Sometimes, I need to remove one or more elements from the list and then return the list to the caller. To remove the comments item as an example I'd do this:

```
host_info.pop(2)
```

I'd prefer to use a constant for each item rather than some magic number.

Then I could use:

```
host_info.pop(comments) # comments is integer 2
```

What's the best way to enumerate these constants so it's simple to maintain them when the list offsets change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to change your list to a dictionary:

```
 keys_list = ['host',...]
 host_info = dict(zip(['stackoverflow.com', '213.213.214.213', 'comments', 'desriprion', 'age'], keys_list))
```

Now you don't have to worry about the key list and if you remove an item from the host_info dictionary it won't affect the key => value associations

or if you only have one host info list:

```
host_info = {'host':'stackoverflow.com, 'ip':'213.213.214.213',...}
```

EDIT:

To remove a key from the host_info use `pop`:

```
host_info.pop('host')
```

If you aren't sure the key is there you can use:

```
host_info.pop('host',None)
```

or you can use:

```
if 'host' in host_info:
    del host_info['host']
```

As a side note AdamKG has a nice comment explaining that you wouldn't want to convert this back to a list.  You could instead do this:

```
 host = host_info['host']
```

This removes the dependence on a "key" mapping list and combines the two lists into a single associative container.

Comment: If I use this method, how would I remove elements and return a list with the elements removed? Thanks.

Comment: @pomodoro: I added some examples to my answer

Comment: You wouldn't, you would pass around a dictionary instead. GWW is suggesting (correctly, I think) that you shouldn't use a list in the first place; since what you're describing is a named mapping rather than a list of items, a dictionary is the best fit.